# Upgrading HTK GazeManager to MRTK v2 Pointer (HandRay...)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

What would be the equivalent code if I want to get hand ray's hit object & position? 
I am looking at this page but it shows event-driven result only.
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Pointers.html#pointer-result

```
    private static Vector3 GetGazePlacementPosition(Vector3 headPosition, Vector3 gazeDirection, float defaultGazeDistance)
    {
        if (GazeManager.Instance.HitObject != null)
        {
            return GazeManager.Instance.HitPosition;
        }

        return headPosition + gazeDirection * defaultGazeDistance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that the code for Gaze would be:

```
        if (CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeTarget != null)
        {
            return CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.HitPosition;
        }
```

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Gaze.html

Answer (score 2):

// The object the right-hand ray hit (from MRTK v2.1.0 release)
GetPointer(Handedness.Right)?.Result.Details?.Object